# Properties window not showing up in C# Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I know i am going to get flamed for this, but for the last week I have been trying to figure out how to open the properties window for my form. I recently switched over to wpf from winforms and I tried to open the properties window but it wouldn't show. It would only show when i ran my program. Do you guys know how to open it up? Sorry for this dumb question, no one I asked could answer this question.
[image]

Comment: when project not run click on control of window and press f4 (then pin this)

Comment: @mehdifarhadi I am trying to open the properties window to set events and so on, i am not having run issues

Comment: During debug, its doesn't open.

Comment: The window only opens during debug, i am trying to open it without having to debug

Comment: @Sh.Imran Do you know how to open it?

Comment: stop the project,select your windows ,go to designer mode,click on window,press f4 (to show properties window)

Comment: @mehdifarhadi Thanks man! I can now finally go back to coding

Comment: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find Properties Window on the **View menu**. You can also open it by **pressing F4** or by **typing Properties in the search box**.

Just select the form and go to:
View -> Properties

[Microsoft official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/properties-window?view=vs-2019).